# Conditional statement for checking input digit is 8 or 6 digit

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I have following code for checking whether the input number is:

1. Empty or not.
2. is number or not.
3. is 8 digit or not.

But cant figure out. If the input is not 8 or 6 digit, it suppose to give error.

```
if ($_POST['phone']==''){
    $has_errors=true;
    $errors[]=__('Phone field is empty','wpestate'); 
} else if(!is_numeric($_POST['phone'])) {
    $has_errors=true;
    $errors[]=__('Phone number entered was not numeric','wpestate'); 
} else if(strlen($_POST['phone']) != 8) {
    $has_errors=true;
    $errors[]=__('The number entered was not 8 digits long','wpestate'); 
}
```

Comment: where is your this function `__(...)` which you are using?

Comment: Note that `is_numeric()` returns true for negatives and floats like `-1.2` and strings like `1e7` so you may instead want to use `filter_input()` with `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT`.

Comment: @AlexHowansky, thank for the tip. But how can I use it this particular code?

Comment: @SahilGulati, I don't what you are talking about, can u plz further elaborate? I am not that tech savvy.

Answer (score 0):

I would count digits with [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to test input.

It's a good idea to test if variable exists, before testing content.

```
if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {
    if ($_POST['phone'] == '') {
              $has_errors = true;
              $errors[] = __('Phone field is empty', 'wpestate'); 
         } else {
            $phone = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $_POST['phone']);
            $plen = strlen($phone);
            if ($plen != 8 && $plen != 6) {
                  $has_errors = true;
                  $errors[] = __('Invalid phone number', 'wpestate'); 
            } // end if invalid length
        } // end if not empty
`} // end if phone received
```